# node.js SMPP EALREADY error

Tags: javascript, node.js, smpp

I am using [Node SMPP](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp) and getting an error:

**Error: connect EALREADY 1.1.1.1:4411 - Local (1.1.1.2:60240)**

```
var smpp = require('smpp');
var session = smpp.connect('1.1.1.1',4411);

session.bind_transceiver({
  system_id: 'test',
  password: 'test'
}, function(pdu) {
  if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
    // Successfully bound
    console.log('bound bind_transceiver')
  }
});
```

I tried to change an IP address and port to non-existing but always EALREADY. thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

did you try following the documentation to the letter?

try this

```
var session = smpp.connect('smpp://1.1.1.1:4411');
```

instead of

```
var session = smpp.connect('1.1.1.1',4411);
```

Comment: yes I tried smpp.connect('smpp://1.1.1.1:4411') also with same result

Comment: Maybe you are trying to bind more than once? the error EALREADY sounds a lot like exists already. Would be nice to have more info on this, are you trying to bind on your own smpp server?

Comment: Solved an issue by reinstalling smpp module.